# How to utilize DirectX/DirectDraw to accelerate animation of a hosted windowless ActiveX control

Tags: visual-c++, directx, activex, gdi, ole

I have a standard GDI win32 application. I have a component which can host windowless ActiveX controls (we use this typically for Flash) by utilizing the IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless/IOleInPlaceObjectWindowless pair of interfaces and therefore calling IViewObject::Draw whenever the hosted control calls back into InvalidateRect. This component is generally modeled after this article: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/controls/article.php/c12229/Transparent-Flash-Control-in-Plain-C.htm

Now my application targets some older hardware and I'm seeing some performance problems with this approach that I don't see when running the same ActiveX control in Internet Explorer. In fact, using process monitor, I'm able to see that IE is using the GPU to some degree to render while my application is not. This has led me to discover that IE is likely using DirectDraw under the covers the achieve the better performance.

So I've taken a stab at doing this within my application, but I'm not seeing anything drawn on the screen. My DirectX/DirectDraw knowledge is nearly nil so that may have something to do with it, but here is what I'm trying to do. Maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong and get me to where I need to be (note that I am just playing around which is why there is no error handling):

1. I create my layered window

   ```
   ivhWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,
   L"MyWndClass",
   NULL,
   WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 
   CW_USEDEFAULT,
   CW_USEDEFAULT,
   CW_USEDEFAULT,
   CW_USEDEFAULT,
   ivhParentWindow,
   ( HMENU )NULL,
   ivhAppInstance,
   ( LPVOID )NULL );
   ```
2. I initialize DirectDraw and create an off screen surface:

   ```
   DirectDrawCreateEx(NULL, (LPVOID*)&pivDD, IID_IDirectDraw7, NULL);
   pivDD->SetCooperativeLevel(NULL, DDSCL_NORMAL);

   DDSURFACEDESC2 tvSurfDesc;
   ZeroMemory(&tvSurfDesc, sizeof(DDSURFACEDESC2));

   tvSurfDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DDSURFACEDESC2);
   tvSurfDesc.dwFlags = DDSD_CAPS | DDSD_HEIGHT | DDSD_WIDTH;
   tvSurfDesc.ddsCaps.dwCaps = DDSCAPS_OFFSCREENPLAIN | DDSCAPS_VIDEOMEMORY;
   tvSurfDesc.dwWidth = 320;
   tvSurfDesc.dwHeight = 340;

   HRESULT tvHR = pivDD->CreateSurface((LPDDSURFACEDESC)&tvSurfDesc, (LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE*)&pivPrimarySurface, NULL);

   LPDIRECTDRAWCLIPPER ptvClipper;
   pivDD->CreateClipper(0, &ptvClipper, NULL);

   ptvClipper->SetHWnd(0, ivhInternalMsgWindow);

   pivPrimarySurface->SetClipper(ptvClipper);
   ```
3. Similar to my initial implementation where I called IViewObject::Draw whenever InvalidateRect is called by the control; I now do basically the same, but utilizing the DC for my DDraw surface instead of a compatible bitmap:

   ```
   RECT rTotal;
   ::GetClientRect(ivhWnd, &rTotal);

   HDC tvhDC;
   pivPrimarySurface->GetDC(&tvhDC);

   HRESULT tvHR = OleDraw(ivViewObject, DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, tvhDC, &rTotal);

   BLENDFUNCTION bf;
   bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
   bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
   bf.BlendFlags = 0;
   bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;

   UpdateLayeredWindow(ivhWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL, tvhDC, NULL, 0, &bf, ULW_ALPHA);
   ```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm basically stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting - not sure what happened

Comment: When you create DirectDraw surface, you don't want to paint via its DC. The whole idea is that DC is a vehicle to transfer data back and forth rarely, e.g. when you need to initialize surface and load initial data. To achieve high performance metrics then you want to blit the surfaces without creating compatible DC every time you paint.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess what I don't understand is how to achieve what Internet Explorer is doing. I know that the IShockwaveFlash object queries for an IDirectDraw3 (which isn't documented) the first time we call OleDraw, but it doesn't seem to be enough to just return a fresh one - I see no benefits doing that. So there is obviously a missing piece here that is eluding me.